# Remover elementos dentro de un rango en Array

Tags: flutter, dart

espero puedan ayudarme.
No sé si haya algún método en dart/flutter que pueda hacer lo siguiente:

Tengo una lista de tipo `String`

```
String fruta1, fruta2;
  List<String> datos = ['pera', 'manzana', 'naranja', 'uva', 'toronja', 'mango', 'fresa'];
```

Tengo dos variables fruta1 y fruta2, quiero empezar a recorrer esta lista conforme a la fruta1 y terminar con fruta2, y poder eliminar las que estén dentro de ese "rango",

por ejemplo si la `fruta1 = "manzana"` y la `fruta2="toronja"`, tendría que eliminar naranja y uva, o al menos decir cuantos recorrió para llegar a la fruta2
espero puedan ayudarme ya que soy nueva trabajando en esto, gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [ask] para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Gracias por corregir, enseguida edito la pregunta:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que obtener el indice de cada elemento y luego eliminas el rango.

```
int fruitIndex1 = datos.indexOf(fruta1);
int fruitIndex2 = datos.indexOf(fruta2);

datos.removeRange(fruitIndex1, fruitIndex2 + 1);
```

removeRange elimina los elementos con indice mayor o igual al indice1 y menores al indice2 (por eso se le suma 1).

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda me sirvió, solo que me eliminaba la fruta principal y la final, y no quería eso, lo solucioné agregando +1 `datos.removeRange(fruitIndex1 + 1, fruitIndex2 + 1);`

Comment: podrías echarme otra mano? lo que pasa es que me envía un error sobre el rango ya que vuelvo a imprimir la lista:  `RangeError (end): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 1..18: 0`